# activeadmin edit prefill fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

In active admin belong_to/foreign key object fields are being showed as as drop down. My requirement was, user should be capable to give an input if the input was new it will create a new entry of foreign key while creating this entry. 
Suppose I have two table Person and Car, every person has exactly one car.

So I added an extra parameter `car_name_str` the following way:

```
form do |f|
    inputs do
      input :name
      input :address
      input :car_string
    end
end
```

I added my controller so that I can take `car_string` and create new car. Now the problem is, when I try to edit, `car_string` remains empty. Now how can I prefil it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read about [nested resources](http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html#nested-resources) in ActiveAdmin?

What you can do is override the **new** action to initialise a new car:

```ruby
controller do
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.cars.build(name: 'my awesome car')
  end
end
```

Then, in your form you can just write something like this:

```ruby
form do |f|
  inputs do
    input :name
    input :address

    f.has_many :cars, heading: nil, allow_destroy: false, new_record: false do |a|
      a.input :name
    end
  end
end
```

This way your form will be initialised with a new car AND, when you'll want to edit your user, you'll get the appropriate values for your car.

Answer (score 0):

```
form do |f|
    inputs do
      input :name
      input :address
      input :car_string,:input_html => { :value => f.object.car.name }
    end
end
```